# Crystal Reports not loading data vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports

In my project, I have a button that, when clicked, is supposed to print all contracts that are currently active, from my SQL Server database. There are hundreds of active contracts, but at the moment, when I press the button, the report form loads but the report doesn't.

I'll do my best to demonstrate this using images and code, but is anybody able to suggest why this happens?

// Code for the print button

```
 Private Sub btnPrintActive_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrintActive.Click

    Try
        Dim objlist As New ReportDocument
        objlist.Load(readIni("REPORTS", directorypath & "connectionpaths.ini") & "\ContractList.rpt")

        Dim info As CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo
        info = New CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo()

        info.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = ""
        info.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = readIni("CONTRACTSTRING", directorypath & "connectionpaths.ini")
        info.ConnectionInfo.Password = ""
        info.ConnectionInfo.UserID = ""
        objlist.Database.Tables(0).ApplyLogOnInfo(info)

        objlist.RecordSelectionFormula = "{tblContracts.Agreement} = 'ACTIVE'"

        Dim f As frmReports
        f = New frmReports(con, acccon, "", 0, "", acccon, , objlist, , )
        f.Show()

    Catch ex As Exception
        errorLog(ex.Message, ex.StackTrace)
        MsgBox("Failed to retrieve contract information from 'database', refer to error log")
    End Try

End Sub
```

// This is the report form, but there is no report

[image]

// Proof that there are active reports

[image]

Comment: Is this a brand new form/report, that has never worked, or one that suddenly is no longer working?

Comment: Because the form is not showing a report, rather than showing a report with no data, have you verified that a) the `.rpt` file is where the app is looking for it, and b) that `frmReports` is loading it?  We might need to see the constructor in `frmReports`.

Comment: helloo @David.. is this resolved?

Comment: @AnnL. Hi, no this was working before, then I changed the database over from Access to SQLServer, and when making the code changes it stopped working. Two of my reports work, but some do not, so I was hoping the same problem would fix them all

Comment: @reds Hi, no this is still broken

Comment: is there any error?

Comment: @reds No error, just as I showed it. Form opens, but the report doesn't.

Comment: Where did you put your query? at your code behind or in a command @crystal report itself?

Comment: @AnnL. another interesting point is that I have another button on this form to print all of the contracts, not just the active one, and that works just fine. The code for this is exactly the same as the code I posted, with the only difference being the line `objlist.RecordSelectionFormula = "{tblContracts.Agreement} = 'ACTIVE'"` is added into this one, as it has a selection to carry out

Comment: @reds the selection query was in Crystal Reports, as a formula query. I removed it, but it was `if {tblContracts.Agreement}=0 then {@UnboundString1} = "ACTIVE" else {@UnboundString1} = "INACTIVE"`

Comment: did you try to debug your code where it is stop

Comment: @reds I tried this, it executes the full subroutine, and misses the Catch, so the code is fine. There's something wrong with the report, I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now fixed. The problem was that I was using 2 database tables in my reports, but was only providing the login information for 1, and the second one wasn't receiving the data from the server, hence why it didn't display. The other thing I did, was changed the fact it was logging in with blank values. My fixed code is now this;

```
 Private Sub btnPrintActive_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrintActive.Click

    Try
        Dim objlist As New ReportDocument
        objlist.Load(readIni("REPORTS", directorypath & "connectionpaths.ini") & "\ContractList.rpt")

        Dim info As CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo
        info = New CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo()

        Dim servername As String = (readIni("SQLConnection", directorypath & "connectionpaths.ini", "servername"))
        Dim database As String = (readIni("SQLConnection", directorypath & "connectionpaths.ini", "database"))
        Dim username As String = (readIni("SQLConnection", directorypath & "connectionpaths.ini", "username"))
        Dim password As String = (readIni("SQLConnection", directorypath & "connectionpaths.ini", "password"))
        Dim provider As String = (readIni("SQLConnection", directorypath & "connectionpaths.ini", "provider"))

        info.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = database
        info.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = servername
        info.ConnectionInfo.Password = password
        info.ConnectionInfo.UserID = username

        objlist.Database.Tables(0).ApplyLogOnInfo(info)
        objlist.Database.Tables(1).ApplyLogOnInfo(info)

        objlist.RecordSelectionFormula = "{tblContracts.Agreement} = 'ACTIVE'"

        Dim f As frmReports
        f = New frmReports(con, acccon, "", 0, "", acccon, , objlist, , )
        f.Show()

    Catch ex As Exception
        errorLog(ex.Message, ex.StackTrace)
        MsgBox("Failed to retrieve contract information from database, refer to error log")
    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to compare this one:

```
 try
            {

                String APPPATH = String.Empty;
                CRPT = new ReportDocument();
                APPPATH = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/CrystalReport/CrystalReport1.rpt";
                //APPPATH = "~/Crystal_report/mosum.rpt";
                CRPT.Load(APPPATH);
                crViewer.RefreshReport();

                CLASS_PROJECT.crystalReportcls rptcls = new CLASS_PROJECT.crystalReportcls();

                ParameterFields paramFields = new ParameterFields();
                ParameterField paramField = new ParameterField();
                ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
                paramField.Name = "sdate";
                paramDiscreteValue.Value = "2016-07-01";
                paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
                paramFields.Add(paramField);


                crViewer.ParameterFieldInfo = paramFields;
                crViewer.ReportSource = CRPT;


                MessageBox.Show("Crystal logged in.");
                CRPT.SetDatabaseLogon("dbusername", "dbpassword");
                rptcls.LogonCrystalReport(crViewer);

            }
            catch (Exception er)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(er.Message);
            }
```

this structure is working for my sample. all you have to do is login the crystal report and the report path itself.